# dismissing GLKViewController does not free memory

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uistoryboardsegue

I got a question to ask.  Currently, dismissing GLKViewController is not deallocating the memory at all.  Rather, it takes more memory whenever I move to the GLKViewController and dismiss it. My game starts at 100MB. Whenever I play a game, it adds up about 10MB. So, if I play it 10 times, it will be about 200MB in the end. It will crash eventually.

This is my only reference to the GLKViewController. I do not call it anywhere in my uiviewcontroller anywhere other than that. I use modal segue to move to glkviewcontroller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    Game *renderer = [segue destinationViewController];
    [renderer setDelegate:self];
    renderer.bomb = bomb;
}
```

And I dismiss it using `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`

Do you know how to fix this problem?  It is wasting so much time right now.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution to this?